# Conditional in the past -- "If Vietnam *would* fall..."

Tags: conditional-constructions

> President Eisenhower had a strategic vision, the Domino Theory.
>   If Vietnam **would** fall, other countries in Southeast Asia **would** fall too.

A lecturer (native speaker) said it on a lesson. Using *would* confuses me. For me it should be at least "If Vietnam **were to** fall." And in the orthodox way it should be "If Vietnam *had fallen*, other countries *would have fallen* too."

Comment: Nice observation. This might hint how native speakers actually deal with hypothetical thoughts. (At least it hints that the Conditionals I, II, and III are insufficient.) I am eager to hear from native speakers too.

Comment: My guess: The first sentence gives you the accurate point of time. The second sentence is written in the view of that point of time. It's future, so to speak. - This, at least, is how it would be in German and I wouldn't be surprised if English and German handle it equally.

Comment: @DamkerngT. - We need to be careful about what we hear in conversation (even in a formal lecture) and what we see in print. Only the latter offers a chance to proofread, revise, and improve. Personally, I'd use: _If Vietnam **fell**, other countries in Southeast Asia would fall too,_ but I wouldn't bat an eyelid at what the professor said.

Comment: I think Eisenhower used *would* because that's want he wanted it to do-  in the same way that you might say, "If only the cord *would* reach over to the sofa I could keep my laptop plugged in while watching this movie."

Comment: Note that there is a certain dialect of American English that was prevalent during parts of the 20th century, used by some members of the upper classes. I read somewhere that this dialect originated in America and contains archaic usage (like involving "shall", "should" and "would"), and imitations of British English. The pronunciation is very clear. For instance the aspirated H is clearly produced. "Why don't you .." comes out as "W..hay don't you".  Watch any old movie from the 1940's and you're likely to hear some of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been under my mind from the start. I know the sentence sounds right, but couldn't explain why. Once I saw Kaz's answer, I read it and I totally agree with the answer, especially the part:

> We can understand it as simply conditionally relating two clauses, which are expressed as a past subjunctive form of "to will": a **subjunctive, irrealis form** of the sentence "If Vietnam will fall, other countries will fall" ...

What I thought was not fully answered is the reason "why" the construct *If ... will ..., ... will ...* can be used, and "how" one could use it.

Today, I read Swan's *Practical English Usage* again, and now I think I've found a good answer.

In Swan's book, there are a handful of entries involved,

> **262 if (7): other structures found in spoken English**
>   **262.1 would in both clauses**
>   Conditional *would* is sometimes used in both clauses of an *if*-sentence. This is very informal, and is not usually written. It is common in spoken American English.

which is close, but I think is not quite related to this question, except for that *How **would** we feel if this **would** happen to our family?* is acceptable as mentioned.

The treatment of ***if ... will*** is explained exclusively under the entry 260. Here is a summary,

> **260 if (5): if ... will**
>   **260.1 results** -- *We'll go home now if it **will make** you feel better.*
>   **260.2 'if it is true now that ...'** -- *If prices **will** really **come** down in a few months, I'm not going to buy one now.*
>   **260.3 indirect questions: I don't know if ...** -- *I don't know if **I'll be** ready in time.*
>   **260.4 polite requests** -- *If you **will come** this way, I'll show you your room.*
>   (*Would* can be used to make a request even more polite.)
>   **260.5 insistence** -- *If you **will eat** so much, it's not surprising you fell ill.*

In my opinion, the entry 260.1 answers this question in particular.

> **260.1 results**
>   We use *will* with *if* to talk about what will happen because of possible future actions - to mean 'if this will be the latter result'. Compare:
>   - I'll give you £100 if I **win** the lottery. (Winning the lottery is a condition - it must happen first.)
>   - I'll give you £100 if **it'll help** you to go on holiday. (The holiday is a result - it follows the gift of money.)

Back to the sentence in questioned: *"If Vietnam **would fall**, other countries in Southeast Asia **would fall** too."* I read *Vietnam would fall* the first time as a speculation. Reading 260.1, I turned to believe that it is more likely that the lecturer was saying that President Eisenhower said this in a context that *Vietnam would fall* **is a result**. I'm not sure which condition it would result from, but since this is about the Domino theory, I believe that it might be a result of some action, or more likely a result from not doing some action.

Here is how I imagine what the lecturer might have wanted to say:

> *We cannot overlook this matter. If Vietnam would fall* (result from overlooking)*, other countries in Southeast Asia would fall too* (result from Vietnam had fallen).

Comment: I don't believe President Eisenhower ever said this, it was the lecturer ***talking about*** President Eisenhower's views. Read the OP's question again.

Comment: Then it must be the lecturer's interpretation. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Addendum: Two years passed. Time flies. I just found a similar sentence expressed in the same pattern (*If ... would ... would ...*) in a book. [Painless American History](https://books.google.com/books?id=Gr0OO11dajwC&pg=PA224) by Curt Lader. At this moment, I don't think 260.1 is really relevant. (Though the speculated interpretation wasn't that bad, and not at all impossible.) It just an informal, spoken way to phrase it. (In other words, the entry 262.1 suffices, and in standard English, we'd use *If Vietnam fell (or were to fall) ..., ... would fall (too)*.)

Comment: A similar question: [If the lava will come down as far as this, we will evacuate these houses.](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/60972/3281). Apparently, the pattern *If ... will ... will ...* used in the way described in 260.1 sounds unnatural/ungrammatical to some native speakers, as evident in [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/260903/11482).

Answer (score 6):

This ties in to the recent question: [Why "Would you mind if I asked you something?" is correct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14353/why-would-you-mind-if-i-asked-you-something-is-correct)

What is going on here is that we have a conditional "if" on a clause which is based on the modal verb combination "will fall".  Since this is in an [irrealis mood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrealis_mood), the verb goes into the subjunctive form. And because the other clause ("other countries ... would fall ...") is in the past, it also goes into the past to agree with that clause.

The usage has somewhat of an archaic ring to it, similar to uses like "Oh if I would be rich", or "Would that he be master". In general, there used to be more flexibility in the language with the verbs "shall", and "will" and their past participles.

Through modern eyes, the sentence looks as if it is derived from the structure "if X will [verb], Y will [verb]" which is not used very much in English.  When we relate two future events together in modern English, we use the present tense for one of them (in English, present tense denotes future actions in some contexts like this one!). So the canonical sentence is "If X [verb]s, Y will [verb]":

> If you eat my candies, I will be upset.
>
> * If you **will** eat my candies, I will be upset.

Since the will-will structure is odd, so is the would-would structure:

> * If you would eat my candies, I would be upset.

So the preferred canonical sentence is:

> If Vietnam **falls**, other countries in South Asia **will fall** too.

And from this form we can derive other tenses. For instance, we can hoist it into the irrealis mood without changing the meaning, by changing both clauses to the past subjunctive form:

> If Vietnam **fell**, other countries in South Asia **would fall** too.

<sub>Note that the past subjunctive is the same as the past tense for "to fall": namely "fell". But for other verbs like "to be", it changes. For instance:</sub>

> <sup>Indicative:  If Vietnam is conquered ...</sup>
>   <sub>Irrealis: If Vietnam **were** conquered ... [Subjunctive past of "to be" = "were"].</sub>

Further, we can derive more tenses from our basic sentence:

> If Vietnam **had fallen**, other countries in South Asia **would have fallen** too.
>
> If Vietnam **is falling**, other countries in South Asia **will be falling*** too.

There is another way to express this, namely the "be + to [verb-infinitive]" form. The basic sentence for that is:

> If Vietnam **is to** fall, other countries in South Asia **will** fall.

This form is not used. Speakers instinctively transform it into the past subjunctive, resulting in this very common form:

> If Vietnam **were to** fall, other countries in South Asia **would** fall.

This "be + to [vinf]" form is quite restrictive in the formation of tense. There is no "will be to fall" or "would be to fall" or "have been to fall". There is "was to fall", which is a special form that has a meaning like "was expected to fall":

> He was to finish the project by the 15th, but it overran right to the end of the month.

So to recap, the original sentence is a little archaic since it uses a would-clause as a conditional:

> If Vietnam would fall, other countries in Southeast Asia would fall too.

It can be understood as being an older form of these modern usages:

> If Vietnam {fell | were to fall}, other countries in Southeast Asia would fall too. [Subjunctive.]
>
> If Vietnam falls, other countries in Southeast Asia will fall too. [Indicative.]

We can understand it as simply conditionally relating two clauses, which are expressed as a past subjunctive form of "to will": a subjunctive, irrealis form of the sentence "If Vietnam will fall, other countries will fall" whose meaning is easy to understand, but which is somewhat grammatically odd to the modern ear.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is a region in the American Midwest where many people habitually put *would* in conditional clauses, as the speaker did in your question. It is mentioned in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_American_and_British_English#Use_of_tenses) on differences between British and American English, although they don't identify it with a specific region of the U.S. This is generally considered incorrect. Avoid doing it.