# If + simple tense, would + bare infinitive (First conditional with would?)

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions, colloquial-language

In a reply to the comment below in this topic: [difference between won't and wouldn't](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37481/difference-between-wont-and-wouldnt)

> If you ask me nicely, I will/would come with you. why here both will
>   and would are correct?

The answer was:

> Strictly speaking they're not both "correct". It should be ask + will
>   (or asked + would for more "hypothetical" phrasing). But some native
>   speakers in casual conversation aren't too fussy about such fine
>   points. –  @FumbleFingers

My listening skills may not be good enough, but I think I heard more than once in some animes where the characters use "would" with simple tense if-clause. Unfortunately I cannot bring up any evidence offhand. I sometimes capture some clips when I watch but I had to wade through hundreds of them if I were to look for a certain one.

Could it be true? I understand it is not grammatical, but, if so, what is it considered? Regional? Very informal? Slang?

**Edit:**

Maybe what I heard was something along the lines of what is in here [First conditional with “would” instead of “will”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112582/first-conditional-with-would-instead-of-will)

> "If it **rains** tomorrow, I **would go** to the cinema" is ***conditional advice***
>   suggesting that the person you're talking to should go to the cinema
>   in the case of rain. –  Peter Shor

Comment: You should probable check the answers given to the question of this link: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65796/difference-between-if-present-will-infinitive-and-if-present-would

Answer (score 2):

> I understand it is not grammatical, but, if so, what do you think of it? Regional? Very informal? Slang?

No, it doesn't sound like slang or regional usage to me (British English). Just sounds like a non-native speaker. It wouldn't be particularly surprising in an [International English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_English) context though.

Comment: Yes, except I'm not keen on the reference to "International English" implying it's some meaningful "dialect" within which such usages might be more acceptable. There's no definition for any such version of English - but if there were, almost certainly it would endorse *simple, non-conflicting* verb forms, so OP's cited usage would probably be explicitly counselled against. And I wouldn't *automatically* think "non-native speaker" in every case, though it might contribute to a growing impression of same.

Comment: Maybe what I heard was something along the lines of what is in here [First conditional with “would” instead of “will”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112582/first-conditional-with-would-instead-of-will)