# Difference between "if + present, will + infinitive" and "if + present, would + infinitive"

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

What is the difference between the following two sentences.

> I will be surprised if he confesses.
>
> I would be surprised if he confesses.

I know that the first is often referred to as first conditional.

I see often sentences like the second one in the form of "if + present, would + infinitive", but cannot find sentences in this form in grammar books.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is a very good question, and you are smart to raise it. Both your sentences are indeed grammatical,³ which is why you often find both sorts. In a nutshell, the one with *would* expresses a proposition that is less likely than the one that uses *will*.

That’s because backshifting is used to indicate this distancing from expectation or reality. It's the same effect as seen with the verb *wish*, where this also happens: *I wish it would rain* or *I wish you would have called me*.

The reason you may not find these in your “grammar books” is because learning materials for non-native speakers always grossly simplify the possible combinations down to a very few reduced but common forms. They do this because they are trying to make sure learners do not accidentally stumble over combinations that actually *are* ungrammatical.³

But despite the best of intentions, by committing this facile reduction they neglect — egregiously to my mind — to teach learners that  English does not have some tiny and frozen set of viable combinations of constructions in the paired halves the way some other languages do.

Many combinations are completely grammatical,³ yet mean something different in a subtly nuanced way. These they do not teach, because the many real possibilities are too confusing for quick classification by learners.

But it does learners a disservice to pretend that these few possibilities are the only ones that exist or the only ones which are grammatical.³ They do not even reflect actual usage by native speakers, as Christian Jones and Daniel Waller observe in their journal entry from the *English Language Teaching Journal* titled [“If only it were true: the problem with the four conditionals”](http://clok.uclan.ac.uk/1531/1/elt.ccp101.full_1531.pdf)¹ when they  write:

> ## It is clear that a division of conditionals into the zero, first, second, and third categories does not adequately reflect actual usage.

If you actually look at corpus occurrences, as they have done, you find that many of the modal combinations frequently found in speech and writing by native speakers are simply not explained to beginners. By attempting to deflect learners from common errors, these errors of omission lead to even more confusion.  And this can do genuine harm, as explained below.

This is hardly the first or earliest time this observation has been made in the professional literature.  In the April 1988 edition of *ELT Journal*, David Maule has a paper titled [“￼￼￼ ‘Sorry, if he comes, I go’: teaching conditionals”](http://eltj.oxfordjournals.org/content/42/2/117.abstract)²  in which he writes (bold emphasis mine):

> Michael Lewis, in his recent book, *The English Verb* (Lewis 1986), makes the 
>   point that **to indulge in artificial simplification is merely to store up
>   trouble for the future.** The damage is compounded when the simplified
>   explanation is backed up by a few well-vetted examples, inconvenient
>   ‘exceptions’ being actively suppressed.
>
> When these two tendencies are unleashed on this area we run the risk of our 
>   students coming to believe that either the standard Type 1 structure is the
>   only way of dealing with real non-past conditions, or, perhaps at a later
>   stage, that it is the ‘correct’ way, and that all other examples
>   encountered are colloquial, or dialectal, or instances of sub-standard
>   usage. Incidentally, it is worth noting that if the collection I made is
>   in any way representative, suppression of other structures would involve
>   ruling out something like 90 percent of real non-past conditionals.

Our resident linguist Professor John Lawler sums this up [here in this comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/245614/third-conditional#comment531921_245614) (bold emphasis again my own):

> They're just mostly-safe combinations of *if..then* clause types; they're not tenses and they don't cover every possibility. Linguists don't have names for the Zero-thru-N types you mentioned, and not for any others that some textbook writer might dream up, either. Generally there is a hypothetical clause of some sort and a conclusion clause of some sort; but there are **hundreds of possible combinations**, and they rarely have to do with tense -- too much depends on the type of condition and its results, which can vary all over the lot.

There really are [**hundreds of possibilities**](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/316123/2085), not just some number you can count on one hand. Just in one part alone, all of these can occur given the right situation:

- If he were to confess
- If he confessed
- If he did confess
- If he had confessed
- If he has confessed
- If he confesses
- If he will confess
- If he shall confess
- If he would confess
- If he should confess
- If he might confess
- If he must confess
- If he dare confess
- If he need confess

Many of those also admit inversion possibilities that skip the *if* entirely:

- Were he to confess
- Should he confess
- Had he confessed
- Did he but confess
- Should he have confessed

(Of course, inversion like this is a much more formal style, one found mainly in literature and formal speeches, not in casual conversation.)

I think you can see how listing out all those would risk quickly overwhelming learners, and would be even more likely to do so were one to go enumerating all possibilities for the other clause as well.

Those are just a few, and most of them mean different things. Some are of course much more common than others, but it is easy for a native speaker to craft various reference frames in which  all of them are “grammatical”.³

It is, unfortunately, also easy for non-native speakers to concoct sentences whose paired clause for those would not be grammatical at all. That is the only reason that learners are taught so tiny a subset of valid conditional propositions: because they might otherwise create combinations that do not make sense to a native speaker.

Here are other examples closer to your original:

- If he does show up, I wouldn’t let him in.
- If he does show up, you shouldn’t let him in.
- If he really wants something, he wouldn’t just take it. I know him well, and I’m sure he’d ask nicely.

If sentences like these are not in your grammar books, then you need better grammar books, because they are completely normal sentences in English.

The best thing learners should take away from all this is that there exist hundreds more valid combinations used daily by native speakers than were ever mentioned in your grammar books.

---

1. *ELT Journal* 65:1 pp 24–32 (2011), Oxford University Press, doi: 10.1093/elt/ccp101.
2. *ELT Journal* 42:2 pp 117–123 April 1988, Oxford University Press, doi: 10.1093/elt/42.2.117.
3. Remember that *grammatical* means nothing more than something that sounds ok to a native speaker. All of the would-be rules you are taught are merely after-the-fact explanations that attempt to describe the things a native speaker does or does not think sounds ok to them. What rules there may be all derive from observations of actual language as it is used by native speakers. This is not math.

   The opposite word, *ungrammatical*, is simply the negation of that, therefore meaning something which a native speaker would think does not sound right.

Comment: Aww . . . this is one of the instances when I regret being a single person.

Comment: This is what I wanted to know. Thank you. By the way, I've read the Japanese translation of your book whose cover is a drawing of Lhama. I visited Boulder for trail running in 2008. Ideal place for running and studying.

Comment: Perhaps I should post this as a question, but how would you explain the difference between 1. "I would be surprised if he confesses." and 2. "I would be surprised if he confessed." ? Is there any *significant* difference?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes: the second one also admits the possibility that he has already confessed but you have not yet learned whether he did or not. the first one does not. Of course the the second also works for the "if he were to confess" type thing.

Comment: If I don't know whether the person has confessed or not,  shouldn't it be: "I would be surprised if he has confessed"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, that would be clearer, I agree.

Comment: Still, you cannot seriously expect a learner's grammar book to include all the possible combinations a conditional sentence might take. Especially beginners, their heads would only spin.That is why the term [mixed conditionals](https://www.google.it/search?q=mixed+conditionals&oq=mixed+conditionals&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22mixed+conditionals%22) was coined, it covers all the bases. :)

Comment: 'Remember that grammatical means nothing more than something that sounds ok to a native speaker.' would be fine if native speakers all agreed on what sounds OK. Quirk and Svartvik drew up an empirical 5-point scale of acceptability based on educated Anglophones' differing opinions. But point made about senselessness of being over-prescriptive. And overall very useful and thorough.

Comment: Such a great answer! Also, that link to that article is a *great* source!

Comment: "Remember that grammatical means nothing more than something that sounds ok to a native speaker." I agree that grammar is in large part *ex post facto*  and that it's certainly not math, but if that statement were completely true, then a native speaker would hardly ever make a grammatical mistake, and there'd be no such thing as a grammarian (for everybody would be one). Frankly, although I've said "I'd be surprised if [present tense]" before, I don't feel comfortable enough to put it in writing. Do you?

Answer (score 0):

Information on the [British Council website](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/modal-verbs/will-or-would) reads-

We use 'will' in *conditionals* with 'if' and 'unless' to say what we think ***will happen in the future*** or present.

So, in the first sentence, you think that his confession 'will' happen in the future.

We use 'would' to talk about ***hypotheses***, what you imagine.

So, in the second sentence, you talk about the hypotheses that he confesses.

---

Note: On the same page, it's mentioned that for 'would', in *conditionals* with words like 'if' and 'what if', the ***main verb is usually in the past tense***.

Comment: I think this answer may look like a good answer at first glance, but there are several subtle underlying problems. Let me verify your understanding for a little. According to your answer, *If I see her I would let her know* is correct. Am I right? Because as you said, "We use 'would' to talk about ***hypotheses***, what you imagine."

Comment: @DamkerngT. if I see her, I'll let her know... because there you don't imagine. Hypotheses would be... I'd travel all across the world, if I become the president.

Comment: I take that your answer is *If I see her I would let her know* is ungrammatical. Am I correct? If that's the case, for the benefit of the OP and other learners, you may want to clarify why you think *if he confesses* in *I would be surprised if he confesses* can be a case of hypothesis or imagination (or any other term you'd like to use), but *If I see her* in *If I see her I would let her know* cannot be one.

Comment: Do you *imagine* her coming? or it's situational? If situational (conditional), I'd prefer 'will'. That's the reason I gave the example of the President. 
@DamkerngT.

Comment: I don't have to have any opinion about that situation in *If I see her I would let her know*, but I believe that you should have a very clear one because you've posted your answer to this question. What makes *if he confesses* okay, and what makes *If I see her* isn't? If you can't even answer that straightforwardly and plainly, how can we trust you that the "very simple and precise information" in your opinion works?

Comment: @DamkerngT. true, I'm clear... but you could have told me the phrase in concern 'simple...and precise' before! Removed!

Comment: Actually, that phrase is only one of my concerns. Still, you haven't explain why you think *would* is okay with *if he confesses*, but not with *If I see her*. If your hypothesis is based on the idea that "We use 'would' to talk about hypotheses, what you imagine", and it applies to *if he confesses*, why wouldn't it apply to *If I see her*? You needn't answer me in comments, but you should make it clear in your answer--make your answer better if you can. We want good answers on our site, right?