# Second conditional in future

Tags: conditional-constructions

I would like to use the second conditional to express something is unlikely to happen.

The problem is this unlikely condition is about the future. Is it still ok to say:

> If I won the lottery next week, I would buy a new car.

Comment: [Related](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/66143).

Answer (score 3):

The sentence makes sense to me as a native speaker, and these sources on second conditionals use such phrasing:

https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-conditional_3.htm

http://www.englishpage.com/conditional/futureconditional.html

Answer (score 3):

> If I won the lottery next week, (then)  I would buy a new car.

If the condition (win the lottery) is considered improbable or counterfactual, yes you can express it by using the 'past tense form' in the if-clause and using 'would' in the then-clause. This is the so-called second conditional.

So your sentence is okay; but it means that you (a) believe the likelihood of winning the the lottery to be improbable or even (b) counter to fact.

The difference in the two are illustrated by the following pair of sentences (these are examples of the above two situations):

1 I could win the lottery next week,  but it is highly improbable since I bought only one ticket and therefore my chances to win are slim to none, and I also happen to be am an extremely unlucky person, and no one in my family has ever won it and probably no one ever will... etc.

2 I could win the lottery next week, if I actually bought a ticket and tried, but since I am not doing that there is no way I can win (my winning is counter to fact).

However, if you are making a prediction about the future, you can just use the present tense in the if-clause and the future tense in the then-clause:

> If I win the lottery next week, then I I'll buy a new car.

You are "predicting" (saying what you will do in the future) what? You are predicting that you will buy a new car  but it is *conditioned* on you winning the lottery.

Your odds of winning may still be extremely low, because you bought only one ticket and etc, and so there is not much difference, really, between this 'future real conditional' and the second conditional discussed above.

Another example: friends are playing poker. Sam has lost a lot of money and the only way he can win back his money is if he wins the next six rounds, which will be played tomorrow (in the future).

Now, his friend and fellow poker player Rick can say either:

> If you won six rounds in a row tomorrow, you would be extremely lucky.

Rick views the event has highly improbable. The sentence takes the form of the second conditional.

Or

> If you win six rounds in a row tomorrow, you will be extremely lucky.

Rick views the event as highly improbable. But the sentence is cast in the 'future real conditional' or 'predictive conditional'. Rick is being "predictive" about Sam being extremely lucky and this is conditioned on Sam winning six rounds.

A counter-to-fact example for the poker players would be

> If you won six rounds in a row next week, you would be really lucky indeed  (since we are playing only four rounds).

See the Wikipedia [article on conditionals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence) for an extended discussion. Part of this answer is based on information contained in it.

Answer (score -2):

Nope. The "next week" part throws everything out of whack.

**If I win the lottery next week, I'll buy a new car.**

**If I ever won the lottery, I'd definitely buy a new car.**

**Should I ever win the lottery, I'll definitely consider buying a new car.**

**Had I won the lottery last week, I would have bought a new car first and foremost.**

Suggested by **Euan M**:

**If I were to win the lottery next week, I would...**

***or***, a completely and irrevocably formal version:

**Were I to win the lottery next week, I would ...**

Here's a pretty decent page on conditionals:

http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conditional2.htm

Yep, it's true. Put "if I ever won the lottery" in quotes and google it. Half of the 30,000 or so results will refer to fiction written in the past tense; the other half, though, is casual everyday talk in the present tense. Go figure, right?

Comment: Are you sure ? From what I understand I should use the present in the condition clause if this is likely to happen which is not the case here!

Comment: @ClementVadi: Hang on a sec. This is nonsense. Let me fix it.

Comment: Using the conditional clause doesn't imply any level of likelihood under any circumstance that I can think of.  Specifically, using the present conditional doesn't imply a greater degree of likelihood that the hypothetical condition will occur than using any other tense.

Comment: As a native speaker, OPs sentence sounds fine, despite what some grammar books will tell you.

Comment: @SenjougaharaHitagi: A lot of things may sound fine. "I ain't got no patience for youse guys" sounds fine too. "I could care less" has been used and abused by native speakers for over fifty years. And while the former is at least comical, the latter is downright disgusting. Eliza Doolittle was a native speaker.

Comment: But I am a native speaker of the standard dialect.

Comment: Also I found a source that has this construction.

Comment: @SenjougaharaHitagi: "But I am a native speaker of the standard dialect." And? ...

Comment: @SenjougaharaHitagi: "Also I found a source that has this construction." The source that contains Eliza Doolittle's intriguing constructions is _Pygmalion_, a play by G. B. Shaw. Would you like a link or two (there's a whole bunch of different versions)?

Comment: It adds evidence toward the idea that it's correct. Unless you're a prescriptivist, in which case this debate is gonna go nowhere.

Comment: @SenjougaharaHitagi: I'm not. Maybe a little bit. I'm a Wagnerite. I'm certainly not an anti-prescriptivist. I believe in the overall harmony of things. If anti-prescriptivists had their way, we'd all be living in caves and communicating in grunts and growls by now. The golden middle ground is the way: it may open doors to mediocrity, but it also allows human genius to do his bit, resulting in good poetry, great drama, and some pretty impressive essays on architecture and the human condition.

Comment: That analogy doesnt work, my source is written in the standard dialect. Even ignoring that, you're essentially arguing that sources in general don't count as evidence. If that's true, why should learners preferentially believe any poster?

Comment: @SenjougaharaHitagi: Really? You're going to use _that_? What sources did Shakespeare use before becoming a source himself? Now I don't now why learners should, or should not, believe anyone or anything, really, but maybe certain native speakers should, provided they have a good ear. Try saying it out loud: "If I won the lottery next week, I would buy a new car." Does it ring true to you? Does it? _Really_? Would you trust a native speaker who talks, let alone writes, like that to translate, say, Mishima into English? _Really_?

Comment: I never said one needed sources. All I'm saying is that your arguement, if valid, would invalidate sources in general. And the sentence sounds fine to me, really. Any awkwardness I attribute to lack of context to explain why we are specifically talking about next week. But in general, I don't find it awkward.

Comment: "If I were to win the lottery next week, I would..." is also an acceptable construct.

Comment: There are two ways of looking at acceptable usage - a descriptive authority and prescriptive authority (and also the prescriptive authority's complement, the proscription authority, which states what is *dis*allowed).  Sometimes they clash, quite legitimately.  The problem with prescriptivists is that they think that everyone should follow their prescriptions.  Unfortunately for them, English has no central prescriptive authority.  Those authorities that do exist - self-proclaimed or generally well-regarded - still have to accommodate changes in actual use over time.  Or end up like King Knut.

Comment: @EuanM: As usual, the truth is somewhere in the middle.

Comment: I am a prescriptivist by nature.  I personally deplore constructs like "There is <(a plural)>,  But it's hard to deny the existence (or indeed, some of the legitimacy) of the descriptivists.  And thank you for the credit - that's  delightful.

Comment: @EuanM: I'm not a great fan of strict adherence to anything; in my view, rules are made to be bent; but I do realize that prescriptivists (i.e. _you guys_) are, in fact, the keepers of wisdom. Without you, the entire structure would crumble. Keep it up.

Comment: @EuanM Using past tense (or subjunctive) plus conditional to express a possible but unlikely future event _is_ the high-register prescriptivist standard.