# Uncertain usage of "should" and construction of the verb

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions, inversion

I am not quite sure whether in the following sentence the construction of the verbs and the rest of wording are correct:

> Should the construction of the University Hospital be completed, this would indeed set new standards - both in terms of size ("one of Germany’s largest university hospitals") as well as with a view to the technological advances.

Comment: Your use of verbs is correct: both *should* and *would* are modals, which require the next form be cast in the infinitive (*should ... **be***, *would ... **set***) and you're using *be* to build a passive, so it must be followed by a past participle (*be **completed***). But your supplement (which should follow a dash, not a hyphen)  strikes me as unnecessarily wordy; I would say "in terms of both size and technological advances"

Comment: Thank you so much  for your help.  Your suggestions are indeed very helpful. The first sentence contains "be completed". have a nice evening, Veronique

Answer (score 5):

Yes, *should* and the other verbs are used properly in your sentence.  With [StoneyB's suggestions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83321/uncertain-usage-of-should-and-construction-of-the-verb#comment160965_83321), the rest of the sentence is okay, too:

> Should the construction of the University Hospital be completed, this would indeed set new standards – both in terms of both size and technological advances.

Of course, this isn't really a proofreading site, and StoneyB covered the basics about how the verbs fit together, so I'd like to focus on the specific question you asked about *should*.  Here are some details about how *should* works in this sort of sentence:

---

### Conditional *should*

Conditional *should* appears in conditional sentences with *if*, adding a small amount of modal meaning, specifically a low degree of doubt:

> 1a. If you experience any difficulty, please let me know.
>   1b. If you **should** experience any difficulty, please let me know.

There isn't much difference in meaning between these two sentences, because *should* doesn't add very much modal meaning to the sentence.  But because it does add some meaning, if there's no doubt at all that the conditional is true, *should* cannot be used.  Imagine a boy criticizing his own father for not helping him:

> 2a. If you're my father, why don't you help me?
>   2b. <sup>#</sup>If you **should** be my father, why don't you help me?

Example 2b is marked with a <sup>#</sup> symbol to indicate that although it's grammatical, it doesn't make sense in the imagined context.  He knows that the listener is father, so there is no doubt whatsoever, so it doesn't make sense to use *should* to express doubt.

Note that in example 2a, the verb *be* is in its finite form *are*, contracted to *'re*.  In example 2b, we added the modal auxiliary *should*, so the verb *be* is now in its plain (infinitive) form. We'll see the same thing in your sentence below.

---

### Inverted conditionals

Besides adding *should*, there's one more element at play.  Certain conditional sentences can be rewritten with subject-auxiliary inversion, omitting *if*:

> 3a. If I had any inkling of this, I would have acted very differently.
>   3b. Had I any inkling of this, I would have acted very differently.

These sentences convey the same meaning, but grammatically there are two differences.  First, we've swapped the subject *I* with the auxiliary *had*.  Second, we've removed the conditional *if* from the beginning of the sentence.  This style is markedly formal and somewhat less common than the more basic style.

Conditionals with *should* are often written in this style.  Let's start with a basic conditional:

> 4a. If the construction of the University Hospital **is** completed, this would indeed set new standards . . .

Now let's add conditional *should*:

> 4b. If the construction of the University Hospital **should be** completed, this would indeed set new standards . . .

Last, let's place it in the formal inverted style.  We'll have to invert the auxiliary *should* with the entire subject noun phrase *the construction of the University Hospital*, and we'll be getting rid of *if*, too:

> 4c. **Should** the construction of the University Hospital **be** completed, this would indeed set new standards . . .

And now we've got your sentence, similar in meaning to 4a, but more formal in tone.

---

The explanation above is based on information and includes examples from Huddleston & Pullum's *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (2002), and can be found on pages 188 (where conditional *should* is described) and 753-4 (where inverted conditionals are described).

In this answer, the <sup>#</sup> symbol indicates that the sentence doesn't make sense in the intended context.

Comment: I mention [inverted conditionals briefly here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/66143).

Answer (score 0):

The modal form here ("Should … be") is roughly equivalent to "If … is". So this is grammatical.