# One sentence with both "could" and "should"

Tags: word-usage

> The envoy could potentially seek Chinese commitment for future support
>   **should** North Korea’s talks with rivals fall through.

In this sentence, what does the "should" mean for?

Here's [the source.](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/asia_pacific/chinas-vip-security-raises-speculation-of-kim-jong-un-visit/2018/03/26/27b1c1aa-315e-11e8-b6bd-0084a1666987_story.html)

Comment: Possibly related: [Uncertain usage of "should" and construction of the verb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83321/uncertain-usage-of-should-and-construction-of-the-verb)

Answer (score 2):

This is called a subjunctive form in a conditional sentence or, in simpler language, [**inversion with should**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Inversion). For the purposes of better comprehension, that *should* can be more or less harmlessly substituted with the conjunction *if* and the meaning, basically, won't change. For example, these two statements are semantically equivalent:

> **Should** a problem arise, call me immediately.
>
> **If** a problem arises, call me immediately.

Your sentence:

> The envoy could potentially seek Chinese commitment for future support **should** North Korea's talks with rivals fall through.
>
> The envoy could potentially seek Chinese commitment for future support **if** North Korea's talks with rivals fall through.

I would be lying if I said that there is no difference between how *should* and *if* are used in these sentences. *Should* as used here, as I previously mentioned, is a subjunctive and as such it's used for expressing a hypothetical state (something that's hypothetical might be true under certain conditions, but generally is not) or a state contrary to reality such as a wish, a desire or an imaginary situation. In this case, I think we're talking about a situation that's hypothetical: something can possibly happen provided that something else happens first. In other words, there is a possibility that the envoy will be seeking Chinese commitment for future support if North Korea's talks with rivals fall through.