# Conditional present or past

Tags: conditional-constructions

Which one is correct?

> 1. What would happen if they **stop** paying you?
> 2. What would happen if they **stopped** paying you?

In what context we can use this? after an event happened or before that.

Comment: Everything you want to know here is probably covered by [this answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/66143/126)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The phrase "what would happen if" indicates that we are talking about something that has not happened yet and is unlikely to happen. We are discussing a hypothetical situation, and the consequences of that situation.

When we make a sentence about a hypothetical situation, we indicate that it is hypothetical by backshifting the tense of the situation- so present becomes past simple, past simple becomes past perfect, etc. We use the same trick for [reported speech](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/reported-speech-backshift.htm).

In principle, the second example is the **correct** answer, because present simple **stop** is backshifted to past simple **stopped**. If you are writing something, this is definitely the right option to use.

In everyday speech, you will hear people describing hypothetical situations  using present simple. Maybe the logic is that they are talking about a future event **will stop**, which gets backshifted to present simple **stop**.

How do we know whether a situation is hypothetical or not?

> If you **don't** stop, I **will** kill you

This is a simple conditional- if this (possible) situation happens, the consequence will be this... no hypothesis. Tenses are present and future.

> If I **were** rich, I **would** buy a heliocopter"

This is understood to be pure hypothesis as I am not rich, so we use the subjunctive.

It's not clear cut, but we tend to use the subjunctive (expressed in most cases as a backshift) in order to give the impression that we think something is unlikely. In the OP's question, the subjunctive is used to talk about a situation that we **hope** is unlikely.

Here is some more information about the [different types of conditionals](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/conditionals-1), but remember that these are simplified guidelines for people learning the language. Actual usage may vary.

Comment: Bookmark-worthy, @JavaLatte .

Comment: Nice answer, but by what authority do you define it "incorrect, in principle" not to backshift given the conditions you mention? *If you don't stop, I'll kill you.* There we have a future hypothetical and its consequence with no backshifting. Your answer suggests it's incorrect or less correct not to do so. Sometimes we use terms like "correct" in a general way, I know. But I think the wording can be important sometimes. *If you don't drop it, I kill you right here.* Is there anything incorrect there?

Comment: I do note that you indicate that one is more formal or likely in writing. Useful distinction.

Comment: @JimReynolds, I have updated my answer.

Comment: How do we deem *what would happen if* as "unlikely" vs *If you don't stop*'s "possible"? Seems like one of those guidelines that may do more damage than good. But I don't know how to answer better.

Comment: It is not so much about **what we deem**, it is about the message **we want to convey**. In fact it is unlikely that I will kill you, but I want to **convey the idea** that it is a probable future outcome.

Answer (score 1):

2) is correct.
If (sentence with a past form of verb), (sentence with would).

What would happen if they stopped paying you?

PS - This sentence structure is used when describing a possibility. Something that has never happened, but what if it happened.