# Is this conditional structure right: “If you didn't see him, he would have gone to England.”

Tags: meaning-in-context

Suppose you tell your friend that he might not meet Alex at the meeting, because Alex is going to another country. So you say:

> If you didn't see him, he would have gone to England.

Here then are my questions:

1. I want to use something I’ve heard called the [**“second *mixed* conditional”**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/66143/141). Is it appropriate for this?
2. Can this structure be used in another interpretation, and if so, which one?
3. Can it be that the condition (meaning the part after the *if*) does not lead to a result (meaning the part after the comma)?
4. How can I express such a situation?

Comment: Reading your first sentence, it is not perfectly clear what you mean, but there are countless possible conditional constructs which may apply here. The two most likely are variants on [Conditional #CXLIV](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/316142/2085): *“If you don't see him, he must have gone to England”* and on #CXLVI: “If you don't see him, he will have gone to England”. The variant is that the first part is from #XXXIV and #XXXVII but the second part from  #CXLIV and #CXLVI respectively. **If this be true, I shall be going to have to renumber my lists of all English conditionals. :)**

Answer (score 1):

I think what your description means, and what your sentence is trying to mean, is this:

"If you don't see Alex at the meeting, it will be because he has already left for London."
or
"If you didn't see Alex at the meeting, it's because he has already left..."

If that is what is meant, I think this sentence is a better way to say it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [past unreal conditional](http://www.englishpage.com/conditional/pastconditional.html) in which the first part of the statement represents a hypothetical condition and the second part represents the hypothetical outcome. The first part of the statement requires a past perfect clause to suggest that action was completed before the following conditional result. The correct way to phrase it would be:

> "If you hadn't seen him, he would have gone to England".

Comment: No, I don't believe so. I think the first part is intended to be "if you don't see him", which is simple present tense. The second part should not be any sort of unreal modal.

Answer (score -2):

Alex may or may not be at the meeting. so you can not use the imrobable condition here. You can use the Type-1, probable condition.

You might say:

> **If you do not see see Alex now at the meeting, He will go to London**
>
> **If you did not/ had not seen him at the meeting, he would have gone to London**.You may call if you  did not with the later part  Mixed condition and    if you had not with the later part unfufilled conditon.But the meaning is  the same.

It means that you met( saw) Alex at the meeting before he went to London.

But your example is faulty.It is not based on cause and consequence.

I think it is better not use conditionals  in your context.

> **By the time you go to the meeting, Alex will have gone to London**

The above is the context you  wanted to talk about.