# If + have + past particle, ...may have + past participle

Tags: conditionals, modal-verbs, sequence-of-tenses

Please consider:

> **If** you **have ever been woken up** before sunrise by the trilling and chirping of birds outside your window, you **may have wondered**: why do birds sing so loud, so early in the morning?

I can’t find anything in grammar books talking about the above sentence pattern. Does it belong to the Zeroth, the First, the Second, or to the Third Conditional (see [here](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/conditionals.html))?

Comment: I fear that you’ve been misled, as [English does not have numbered conditionals](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/316142/2085).  You should probably take this to [our sister-site for English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/66143/141). The first and last verbs (*have, sing)* are in the present tense and the modal verb *may* is the present-tense version of the *may/might* pair. English has no sequence-of-tenses rule. It’s just in whatever set of tenses that the speaker chooses to use, each with a slightly different nuanced meaning.

Comment: The sentence is grammatical. What do you want to know about it? If you want to call it the Eighteenth Conditional, that's OK with me, but it doesn't tell you anything you didn't already know.