# Is there anyone can help me to understand the sentense?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, conditionals, sequence-of-tenses

I think this sentence is a mixture of the second conditional and the third conditional:

> If it did, the rat would not have known it.

But I have heard the line in *The Big Bang Theory*.

How can I understand its meaning?

Comment: First, by understanding that [**there is no such thing** as a “second conditional” or a “third conditional”.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/66143/141) I'm truly sorry, but you have been grievously misled.  English does not work that way, and that's why you're confused. The way English really works is extremely different from the fake model that ESL students are given. Native speakers are never taught your model, and linguists completely ignore it, in both cases because it is meaningless. It is harmful to learn because it just is not true.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. I will pay more attention to the real conversations rather than the fake model.

Comment: For learners there is nothing wrong or false about studying the so-called four conditionals: zero, first, second, and third. Think of it as a good solid foundation that allows you to understand their meanings and usage. In fact, a large number  of conditionals in English spoken by native speakers fall into one of the aforementioned categories.

Comment: In order to understand the *meaning* of the quotation it needs more context. What did the rat do or not do? Please provide the name of the episode and the number of the season.