# What is the right form of the verb in brackets?

Tags: conditionals

“Hey. Do not touch the car. The alarm (go off) ______ if you touch it.”

What is the right form of the verb phrase in brackets? The possible answers found are “goes off” which describes a fact about the car and “will go off” which implies a warning about the car’s alarm system. Since there is no big difference between the two, I wonder whether I can use both of them in the given context.

Comment: You asked this same question two days ago: [Comparing “Zeroth” and “First Conditionals” in similar contexts](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/302805/comparing-zeroth-and-first-conditionals-in-similar-contexts) If you didn't get what you needed then, ask for clarification on the previous question - don't just ask it again with a different title.

Comment: I tried to add clarification to the previous question but there has been no update on it. Another reason is the question was migrated out of the section for English Language Learners for not satisfying certain conditions. So I decide to modify and post the question again here to get some more answers to it. I’m really looking forward to hearing what you think about the answer to the question. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Here is the response to my edits: “You do not have edit privileges. Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed…”. 
I have recently tried one more time and couldn’t save my edits. This is the latest response: “ You can only post 1 time each day due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from your network. We apologize for any inconvenience. See the help center for more.”

Comment: I don't know why you can't edit your own question. Maybe it's something to do with it having been originally asked on ELU, then migrated here to ELL. Are you saying that the answer from jeffUK on the original question *doesn't* tell you what you want to know, AND you're unable to post a comment underneath his answer asking for clarification? Maybe we need help from a moderator.

Comment: Hi. I appreciate JeffUK’s input. He did answer the question as expected. But that’s just one single opinion. I still hope to hear more from others about their thoughts on the problem raised before I draw any conclusions about it. Unfortunately, after JeffUK’s post, the question was migrated to another section where I have not found any new answers (except unpleasant comments about the question itself). That’s why I wanted to clarify the original question, but didn’t get my edits updated.