# Though seems conditional Type 2, it is not fully compliant to Type 2. So, is such a Type 2 still acceptable: if+present, would

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language, conditional-constructions

The following sentence is from a text in which someone is complaining about his brother who has not been interested in his elderly mother. (Here is the link: https://www.insider.com/why-i-cut-contact-with-brother-sibling-estrangement-2020-5)

**"I wouldn't be surprised if the next and final time I see my brother is at my mother's funeral."**

One side of the sentence is **would**, and the other side of the sentence is **present**, which do not seem to fall in any of the conditionals, although it seems similar to Type 2. Thinking about the conditional Type 2, if one part of the sentence is structured with **would**, the other part should be in **(simple past)**, but this sentence is not structured that way either.

So, what structure is it?

Is it really correct, or should it have been structure like this: **"I wouldn't be surprised if the next and final time I see my brother WAS at my mother's funeral."**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*I wouldn't be surprised if...*" is an idiomatic expression that means, "I strongly believe that ... is going to happen". It doesn't follow the normal rules of grammar.

It has the structure of an unreal (technically, "*irrealis*", but I'm guessing you know what I mean) conditional, but the meaning of a real ("realis") conditional. It's grammatically correct to use either real or unreal grammar after it, though real grammar is only used in speaking and informal situations.

In particular with this sentence, since it's about the real future, it's awkward to have simple past verbs. But this version is also correct:

> I wouldn't be surprised if the next and final time I **saw** my brother **were** at my mother's funeral

Comment: My ear wants to pair irrealis *if-were* with *then-would* as a sort of "If X **were** so, then Y would happen" sort of sentence: *"If the next time I saw him **were** at my mother's funeral, this wouldn't surprise me in the slightest."* But of course the OP's quoted sentence is just fine because [English doesn't have numbered conditionals](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/66143). :)

Comment: @tchrist Numbering conditionals is a useful tool (like learning musical notation) to which more forms can be added. Otherwise, starting points are fuzzy.//I wouldn't be surprised if is not an idiomatic expression. Because you can say: I am surprised that, etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The verb surprise is not an idiomatic expression.
The sentences below can all be expressed with: **be surprised/was surprised**

It surprises me that he is a rich man. [I am surprised that etc.]

It surprises me that he **was** a rich man. [is no longer rich]
It doesn't surprise me that he **is** a rich man. [ongoing condition]

It surpris**ed** me that he **is** a rich man. [ongoing condition of richness]

It surpris**ed** me that he **was** a rich man. [at the time]

Conditional surprise: It wouldn't surprise me if he **were** a rich man. **But I don't know if he is rich.** [I wouldn't be surprised if he were a rich man. Same meaning]

Conditional surprise but not about the richness: It wouldn't surprise me if he **is** a rich man. [is a  rich man is an ongoing condition]

"I wouldn't be surprised if the next and final time I see my brother **was** at my mother's funeral." This is an unreal conditional, as the mother is still alive.

"I wouldn't be surprised if the next and final time I see my brother **is** at my mother's funeral." The mother's condition here is that at some point she will have a funeral. So, it expresses a different thought than putting it in the conditional.

Comment: Related ELU questions: [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/270445/2085), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/284854/2085), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/206005/2085), [4](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/211222/2085), [5](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/117504/2085). The last link covers uses "In expressions of **surprise** or its absence, approval or disapproval, of some present or past fact," as in the rather formal-sounding *I was surprised that he should say such a thing!*

Comment: @tchrist Not all expressions of surprise include the verbs: to surprise and to be surprised. Why don't you state the **fact** that there is no idiom here under the other answer?

Comment: “I was surprised that he should say such a thing.” is not at all the usage here. Your entry was about modals.

Comment: Because for something to be [idiomatic](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/idiomatic) means only that it's natural to a native speaker; that is, it's grammatical. It  **does not** mean that it's an [idiom](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/idiom) with a meaning that is not deducible from its words alone. The other answer therefore simply says that it is grammatical, not that it has some hidden meaning. Nobody mentioned an idiom.

Comment: "I wouldn't be surprised if..." is an *idiomatic expression*".  Something may be expressed idiomatically but it is not an idiom aka idiomatic expression.

Comment: The question tag [tag:idiomatic-language] "is for questions about whether or not a particular phrase or sentence is a usual or common way that fluent English speakers might express something."

Comment: I was commenting on the comment. Not the tag. Tags are one thing, sentences written out by participants are another. Idiomatic language is another way to say something is idiomatic but not to say it is an idiomatic expression aka idiom.