# will vs would usage

Tags: modal-verbs, will-would

Can I use "will not" instead of "would not" in the sentence given below?  If so, What is the difference?

> No matter what I did, Ken **wouldn't** do what I told him.

Answer (score 2):

> No matter what I **did**, Ken **wouldn't** do what I **told** him.

In this sentence, the verb **[will](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/will)** refers to what Ken is able or willing to do.

The sentence is talking about a situation in the past, so all of the verbs are in the past tense. If you were talking about a present situation, you would use present tense:

> No matter what I **do**, Ken **will not** do what I **tell** him.

In your original sentence, you cannot replace **wouldn't** by **will not** unless you change all of the verbs, and changing all of the verbs changes the time of the whole sentence.

Answer (score -2):

According with [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37481/difference-between-wont-and-wouldnt)

No, you can't because **woudn't** is for a hypothetical future and **will not** is for plans.