# It won't have BEEN millions... (making assumptions about the past)

Tags: will-would, tense-agreement, future-constructions

I am still unsure about when to use 'would' and when 'will' while making conjectures about the events in the past. Is the difference merely in the degree of certainty?

Besides, I am not sure what difference is between:

1. It won't have BEEN millions...       (stressed main verb)
2. It won't have been millions...          (unstressed main verb)

Source:
https://youtu.be/OunzCSCt43w?t=806
Would I Lie to You S17 E6. Non-UK viewers. 2 Feb 24

Comment: The questions are a little confusing, you might want to narrow it down -- break it into separate questions about conditional phrasing (would vs. will?) and the "have been" phrases you give as examples.

Comment: Please explain the context in which you think it makes sense to put heavy stress on the word ***been*** here. Usually, if there was any stress at all, it would normally fall on ***millions*** (often, reflecting speaker emphasizing that someone else's reference explicitly or implicitly exaggerated the number). OR stress might be put on ***won't*** when speaker is baldly refuting someone elses claim that it ***was*** "millions". I don't say stress *can't* be put on ***been***, but it's certainly unlikely for a native Anglophone.

Comment: (Your link to a source video doesn't work for me, based in the UK.)

Comment: The speaker is joking, he does not stress BEEN, and there's a clash between *won't* and *been* as future and past. Not recommended for learners, if that's the question. "It won't have been millions" says that in the future, we **will not see** that the numbers **have been** (were) that high.

Comment: I just realised the link is for "non--UK viewers", so I switched to a US vpn to access it. I'd say David Mitchell *does* in fact place "secondary stress" on ***been*** there. It's not "primary stress", because he's not *really* disagreeing with what previous speaker said - he's asking for ***clarification***. Reason being she said *it **felt like** millions*, so he's simply pointing out that there's obviously a difference between what it ***felt like***, and what it actually ***was***. He might just as well have stressed *It wasn't **actually** millions...* or even *It **wasn't** millions...*

Comment: ...because stressing *any* instance of the verb [TO *(**actually**)* BE] in that context simply contrasts "the reality" with *what it **felt like***. I didn't listen to the full context, but it's obviously *not* a situation where whatever's being counted really could be in the millions (for all I know, it's *"How many people came to your party last night?"*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Wow! Thanks a lot for the detailed and lucid explanation! This is something I was totally unaware of!

Comment: I don't understand why someone downvoted your question. Perhaps irritated that they couldn't access the link, same as me originally. The significance of emphatic *(really) **BE*** X as opposed to ***BE like*** X *(**feel, seem** like)* just feels obvious and natural to me as a native Anglophones, but I suppose it's all very obscure for a learner. Not something you'd normally find explained in a textbook! If no-one else posts an answer I might copy these comments in later.

Comment: There are 2 separate questions here. [This question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37481/difference-between-wont-and-wouldnt) already covers won't vs wouldn't.

Comment: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/future-continuous-future-perfect All this is explained on that site. In English, you can stress anything in a sentence to change its meaning. The tense is future perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand "it won't have been millions" as a statement about the past but as a projection into the future concerning the as yet unknown facts of a recent event.

> Man, on the TV it looked like the crowd at the capitol was in the millions!
>
> -- That was just the camera angle. You'll see. It won't have been millions.

If we were speaking about the past, we'd use **wouldn't**:

> Millions of Londoners died from the plague in the 14th century.
>
> --No, it wouldn't have been millions. The population of London in the 14th century is thought to have been well under 100,000.

Comment: You mean, 'It won't have been millions... ' = 'The evidence will (or may?) emerge in the future that this statement was inaccurate' ?

Comment: Close. The evidence *will surely emerge* that your sense of the number is greatly exaggerated. The speaker is confident that the other person's number is wrong.