# if + would, present tense

Tags: word-usage, tense, conditional-constructions

> If you decide to accept we would love to discuss it further.

"Would" is not supposed to go with if, but "would love" is something of an idiom and I am not sure what other word I can use. "Will love" doesn't sound right.

Comment: *If you decide to sell the car, we would make an offer.*  If...would is fine.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, is this considered acceptable too: "If you give me the money, I would do it"? And, are there any specific rules about it, or are all sentences with *would* in the *then*-clause and a present-tense verb in the *if*-clause considered acceptable, just like the traditional "present-tense + *will*" and "past-tense + *would*" forms?

Comment: [This answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/14367/1301) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the standard conditional form of this sentence:

> If you decide to accept, we will discuss it further.

This version comes across as very direct and doesn't necessarily imply that there's any preference one way or another for further discussions. There are a number of ways to soften the sentence and emphasize a desire for the other person to accept:

> If you decide to accept, we **would love** to discuss it further.
>
> If you decide to accept, we **would be happy** to discuss it further.
>
> If you decide to accept, we **would be glad** to discuss it further.
>
> If you decide to accept, we **would be pleased** to discuss it further.

In each case, then word "would" is being used as a modal verb to express politeness, rather than the past tense of "will".

Comment: Thank you! I had that feeling that "would" is polite, but somebody confused me that it should not be used with if and present tense and it is hard (maybe impossible) to find any set of rules that will show all the cases.

Comment: What about "If you decide to accept, we will love to discuss it further"? Can it be used to emphasise our desire and express politeness, like the *would love* version?