# Would you mind if I "opened/open" the window

Tags: conditional-constructions

Which one of the followings is correct?

> Would you mind if I **opened** the window?

or

> Would you mind if I **open** the window?

Ps:
like 2 if condition
If I were you / If I was you (both is okay but usually used to "were")
so it is the same condition or not?

Comment: [This](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/14367/1301) may answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would you mind if I **opened** the window?

This is the most grammatically correct usage. You should use this.

> Would you mind if I **open** the window?

This, while technically incorrect, is still used a lot by native speakers.

Your other two sentences are in a similar situation:

> If I **were** you

This is correct. While normally we use **was** in the singular case, for hypotheticals we use **were**.

> If I **was** you

This, while technically wrong, is still used all the time by native speakers who don't understand the nuance of the *subjunctive mood*.

Comment: Verb after if gotta be past tense?(+ed)

Comment: @Ives It's actually really complex, probably the most complex part of English IMO. It depends on the Irrealis mood: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrealis_mood

Comment: If the Irrealis were the future, I can still use past tense after `if`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Could you rephrase that?

Comment: For example, `if I went to swimming class this summer(not summer yet)`, is this correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. `If I go to swimming class this summer` is also fine, they just have different moods.

Comment: Is `went` more Irrealis than `go` here? (less possibility)

Comment: Irrealis moods are a group of grammatical 'mood's that convey the subtle nuance of things that aren't certain. A full lesson on them isn't really in the scope of Stack Exchange, but there's a good explanation of them here: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/moods

Answer (score 1):

This is the 2nd would condition. Both conditions are unreal.

**For example:**

Would you accept that job, if they offered it to you ?

```
1. He has not accepted the job.
2. He has not been offered the job.
```

This is the same as

```
1. He does not feel annoyed at that moment.
2. The window has not been opened.
```

> Would you mind if I opened the window

The above sentence is correct.

Answer (score 0):

> Would you mind opening the window? - it's a request Would you mind if
>   I open the window? - it's asking for permission
>
> Would you mind not smoking? - it's asking sb to stop smoking, or not to start doing it when we see sb is going to do it.
>   Would you mind if I smoke? - it's asking for permission to smoke

```
Are these both acceptable and the same in meaning?    
    "Would you mind if I opened the window?"    
    "Would you mind if I open the window?"    
Both are quite acceptable. The meaning is identical.     
Some people believe the use of "opened" makes the request a little more polite
```