# If + past tense + would VS If + present tense + would

Tags: clauses

1. I would/(will) eat it if you **add** more sugar.
2. I would eat it if you **added** more sugar.

What are the differences between them?

Can we use "would" instead of "will" to make the first sentence more polite??

Comment: [This answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/14367/1301) may help.