# Confused with conditional sentence

Tags: conditional-constructions

"If I would’ve heard that before I would’ve named one of the cars Jalopnik" (from http://goo.gl/KvE2tB)

"Would have + P2" in main and dependent clauses seems odd to me. Is this correct?

I expected:
"If I had heard that before I would’ve named one of the cars Jalopnik".

Comment: Related: See PEU's "262.1 would in both clauses" here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/14668/3281.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Re your [v good] ref: 'common in American spoken English' - but, wow, that looks weird to a Brit. Had've at a push, but not would've. Preferably just "If I'd heard…" to my ear.

Answer (score 1):

When talking about something [hypothetical](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/verbs/if-i-would-have-vs-if-i-had/) in the past, many English speakers use the conditional perfect (if I would have done) when they should be using the past perfect (if I had done).

The correct formulation, as you expected is:

> If I had heard that before I would’ve named one of the cars Jalopnik.